# maven assembly:single Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am moving my maven build from 2.2-beta5 to 2.2. As per documentation assembly:assembly is deprecated and I am trying to replace it by assembly:single. I have been trying various configuration but it is still not working I usualy get the follwoing error: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.

```
   <plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<executions>
 <execution>
  <id>make-assembly</id>
  <phase>assembly</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>single</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
   <finalName>${env}.${project.version}</finalName>
   <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
   <filters>
    <filter>src/main/filters/${env}/${build.env}/filter-common.properties</filter>
    <filter>src/main/filters/${env}/${build.env}/filter-${user.name}.properties</filter>
   </filters>
   <descriptors>
    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor>
   </descriptors>
  </configuration>
 </execution>
</executions>
```

**Executed with** : mvn clean package assembly:single  install antrun:run

I have also tried moving the configuration out of the execution tag but this causes the same problem. When removing assembly:single from the command the plugin i snot executed. Pleae let me know what is the corect way of executing this plugin ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error I notice that by adding this to the package phase, it will work just fine:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
    <configuration>
    <finalName>${env}.${project.version}</finalName>
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    <filters>
            <filter>src/main/filters/${env}/${build.env}/filter-common.properties</filter>
            <filter>src/main/filters/${env}/${build.env}/filter-${user.name}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
            </execution>
    </executions>
                    </plugin>
```